React Slick infinite slide transition issue
It seems that having infinite set to true causes a bug to occur in which after reaching the end of the slides it does not smoothly continue over to a clone but rather glitches back to the first element. The cloned elements are visible but it does not flow over to them.
Here is my settings for it:
const newArrivalsSettings = {
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    // centerMode:true,
    speed: 500,
    arrows:true,
    dots:true,
    // variableWidth: true,
    initialSlide: 0, // Ensure first slide is initially active
nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
  customPaging:( i:any) => (
    <div
      style={{
      }}
    >
     
    </div>
  ),
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        initialSlide: 0,      
          infinite: true,

        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow:1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        initialSlide: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
  };```


I have set infinite:::true , I am expecting it should have a smooth between the last element and first element. **Also I have set the width of Active slide (current slide) more than the rest of the slides.**


Make sure you are importing react-slick css files correctly.
